Не работает обработки сообщения телеграм пользователя с помощью gpt
Пишу телеграм бота, захотел добавить туда gpt для обработки вопросов. Написал код. Он работает, но со своими нюансами. Буквально вчера обрабатывал только первое сообщение пользователя в телеграм боте (выводил корректный и правильный ответ с помощью gpt), а на последующие выводил ошибку. Сейчас же не обрабатывает ни одного сообщения и выводит ошибку. При установки пакета "nodriver" (по рекомендации ошибки) происходит следующее - ответ не выводится, и пользователя перебрасывает на сайт You.com. Что не так написал? Как исправить ошибку? Как обрабатывается запрос через gpt бесплатный без токена бота gpt? Хороший ли вариант использовать такую структура запроса через gpt? Лучше работать с токеном gpt? Что классное можно добавить в структуру "response = client.chat.completions.create()" ещё?
Сам код:
import telebot  # импорт pyTelegramBotAPI
from g4f.client import Client

# ID телеграм-бота
token_bot = '6399027349:AA4784837sXvl6oe8n4qP0'
# взаимодействие через ID с нашим телеграм-ботом
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token_bot)

client = Client()


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda _: True)
def handle_message(message):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4o",
        messages=[{
            "role": "user",
            "content": message.text}],
    )
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=response.choices[0].message.content)


# автономная (постоянная) работа телеграм-бота
bot.infinity_polling()

Ошибка вывода:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Test_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\g4f\providers\retry_provider.py", line 324, in raise_exceptions
    raise RetryProviderError("RetryProvider failed:\n" + "\n".join([
g4f.errors.RetryProviderError: RetryProvider failed:
Liaobots: ResponseStatusError: Response 500: Error
You: MissingRequirementsError: Add .har file from you.com or install "nodriver" package | pip install -U nodriver


В ошибке говорится, что надо установить nodriver (pip install -U nodriver), может быть, это решит проблему.

При установки пакета "nodriver" (по рекомендации ошибки) происходит следующее - ответ не выводится, и пользователя перебрасывает на сайт You.com.
